# How to improve insert speed with index on text column

Tags: postgresql

I am using Postgresql database for our project and doing some performance testing. We need to insert millions of record with indexed columns. We have 5 columns in table. I created index on integer only then performance is good but when I created index on text column as well then the performance reduced to 1/8th times. My question is how I can improve performance when inserting data using index on text column?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is *you can't*.

It is well known that adding indexes on db columns is like a 2 edged sword:

- on one (positive) side it adds improved speed to you read queries
- on the other, it adds performance penalty to `insert/update/delete` operations and your data will occupy a little more disk space

A possible solution would be to use some full text search engines like [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) which will index your text entities in your DB

Comment: Thank you! Please correct me if I am wrong. Full text search engines are used to improve the performance for read queries. It will not help to improve performance for write.

Comment: exactly - but then you can keep your table that is under heavy inserts with basically no indexes on it (except for the PK of course)

Comment: so, you'll have your DB table without indexes - which guarantees fast insert speed - and you'll query that using Sphinx, or SOLR (the fulltext search engine)

Comment: @Saurabh: That is only half true. `DELETE` can profit heavily from a fitting indexes. Even `INSERT` *can* profit if conditions have to be checked in triggers - but that's the exception. It all depends on your precise situation.